# Query with better performance

Tags: sql

I have an SQL query running too slow because a 'custom column'. how can i do it in a better way?

there's the code:

```
select
    VBI.ID_acesso,
    VBI.data_hora  AS Data_Hora_Entrada,
    VBI.data      AS Data_Entrada,
    VBI.Sentido   AS Sentido,
    VBI.Unidade    AS Unidade,
    replace(replace(VBI.Documento,'.',''),'-', '') AS Documento,
    VBI.Tipo_Documento,
    VBI.Nome,
    VBI.Tipo_Usuario AS Tipo_Usuario,
    VBI.Categoria AS Tipo_Pessoa,
    VBI.Empresa_Usuario,
    VBI.Visitado,
    VBI.Tipo_Documento_Visitado,
        (
        SELECT
            MIN(VBI2.DATA_HORA)
        FROM
            Ses.dbo.VIEW_Mand_Dashboard_BI VBI2
        WHERE
            VBI2.documento = VBI.documento
            AND VBI2.ID_acesso > VBI.ID_acesso
            AND VBI2.Tipo_Documento = VBI.Tipo_Documento
            AND VBI2.Sentido = 'Saída'
            AND VBI2.data_hora >= VBI.data_hora
         ) as Data_hora_Saida
FROM
    Ses.dbo.VIEW_Man_Dashboard_BI VBI
WHERE
    VBI.[data] >= CONVERT(DATE,'2021-10-01')
      and VBI.Sentido = 'Entrada'
    and VBI.Empresa_Usuario  NOT IN ('CAMPSEG')
order by
    VBI.Unidade, VBI.data_hora;
```

The part that is taking my query slow is the column: **Data_hora_Saida**

Comment: `MIN(VBI2.DATA_HORA)` is probably the problem. How many rows do you have in that table?

Comment: Tag only the database that you use.

Comment: around 4-5 milions rows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe try

```
(SELECT TOP 1 *
  FROM Ses.dbo.VIEW_Mand_Dashboard_BI VBI2
  WHERE VBI2.documento = VBI.documento
  AND VBI2.ID_acesso > VBI.ID_acesso
  AND VBI2.Tipo_Documento = VBI.Tipo_Documento
  AND VBI2.Sentido = 'Saída'
  AND VBI2.data_hora >= VBI.data_hora
  ORDER BY VBI2.DATA_HORA
) as Data_hora_Saida
```

Comment: DATA_HORA = DATETIME

Comment: Did you try it and it doesn't work? `TOP` should work with `datetime`.

Comment: Try only this `SELECT` statement check if it gives you the right results, then add it to full statement and see what it gives you.

Comment: thanks for the tip.. that TOP 1 reduced a good time performance

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to use sub-query, the column **Data_hora_Saida** instead of adding in the SELECT section

Comment: sorry i m new. how can i do that?